# "Python is not installed" cuando si está instalado para usar en docker

Tags: python, docker, windows10, wsl

Estoy teniendo un problema al utilizar el tutorial de OpenMTC usando Docker (https://www.openmtc.org/doc.html).
El problema viene cuando utilizo el "gateaway" (tercer paso) pero me dice el mensaje de

```
Python is not installed. Exiting now.
```

Pero clara mente lo tengo uinstalado.
Estoy usando la consola de Bash sobre Windows 10 con Ubuntu. Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema al instalarlo, luego me enviaba a la store de windows. prueba en la consola directamente con python

Answer (score -1):

El comando `create-binary-docker` requiere Python instalado en tu computadora.
Instala una version de python en tu equipo antes de ejecutar el comando, o verifica que `python` esta incluido en el PATH de ejecucion.

```
# check if python is installed
if ! $(which python) --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Python is not installed. Exiting now."
    exit 2
fi
```

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: El problema es que ya lo tenía instalado en windows, además de que python3 si está instalado en el bash de base.
Aun así el script me dice que no está instalado.

Comment: Quiza porque esta buscando `python` y no `python3`. Puedes probar que pasa si ejecutas  `python --version` en la misma linea de comandos? Estas usando Git bash como linea de comandos?